# Why is Rails not finding my jbuilder template or not rendering it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jbuilder

I have a route that looks like this:

```
resources :property_searches, :path => 'search'
```

That generates these routes:

```
 property_searches GET    /search(.:format)                                                             property_searches#index
                   POST   /search(.:format)                                                             property_searches#create
new_property_search GET    /search/new(.:format)                                                         property_searches#new
edit_property_search GET    /search/:id/edit(.:format)                                                    property_searches#edit
    property_search GET    /search/:id(.:format)                                                         property_searches#show
                    PUT    /search/:id(.:format)                                                         property_searches#update
                    DELETE /search/:id(.:format)                                                         property_searches#destroy
```

This is what I have in my `PropertySearchesController#Index`:

```
@properties = Property.first(5) #This is just a test

respond_to do |format|
  format.html {}

  format.json {}

  format.fullsearch do
    render :formats => [ :js ]
  end

  format.livesearch do

  end

  format.filtersearch do
    render :formats => [ :quicksearch ]
  end
end
```

Then in my `views/property_searches/index.json.jbuilder`, I have the following:

```
json.properties do
  json.array!(@properties) do |property|
    json.name property.name
  end
end
```

When I visit `/search.json` in my address bar, this is what I get in my logs:

```
Started GET "/search.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-14 14:22:32 -0500
Processing by PropertySearchesController#index as JSON

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 993.8ms
** [Raven] Missing template property_searches/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/hj-project/app/views"
  * "/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hjproject/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views"
  * "/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hjproject/gems/comfortable_mexican_sofa-1.8.5/app/views"
  * "/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hjproject/gems/formatted_form-2.1.2/app/views"
  * "/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hjproject/gems/declarative_authorization-0.5.7/app/views"
  * "/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hjproject/bundler/gems/comfy-blog-fcf9e4e88948/app/views"
  * "/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hjproject/gems/xray-rails-0.3.1/app/views"
 excluded from capture due to environment or should_capture callback

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template property_searches/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/hj-project/app/views"
  * "/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hjproject/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views"
  * "/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hjproject/gems/comfortable_mexican_sofa-1.8.5/app/views"
  * "/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hjproject/gems/formatted_form-2.1.2/app/views"
  * "/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hjproject/gems/declarative_authorization-0.5.7/app/views"
  * "/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hjproject/bundler/gems/comfy-blog-fcf9e4e88948/app/views"
  * "/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hjproject/gems/xray-rails-0.3.1/app/views"
):
  actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
```

I also tried putting this in my `respond_to` block instead:

```
  format.json { render json: {properties: []} }
```

And even though it doesn't produce the same error, when I go to the page I literally just see this on the page:

```
{"properties":[]}
```

It doesn't show me the values within `@properties` that I set.

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

**Update 1**

When I render the collection directly, it works, i.e. when I do this:

```
format.json { render json: @properties }
```

However, that doesn't iterate over it. It just spits out the values, and the log looks like this:

```
Started GET "/search.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-14 14:50:28 -0500
Processing by PropertySearchesController#index as JSON
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "admins" WHERE (admins.superadmin = 't')
  PropertyCurrencyType Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "property_currency_types".* FROM "property_currency_types" WHERE "property_currency_types"."name" = 'USD' LIMIT 1
.
.
.
  Agent Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "agents".* FROM "agents" WHERE "agents"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
  Property Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties" LIMIT 5
Completed 200 OK in 2574.6ms (Views: 8.8ms | ActiveRecord: 595.1ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

Silly me. I assumed that Rails had automatically added the `jbuilder` gem to my `Gemfile`, but it turns out that it doesn't happen until Rails 3.2. This app I am working in is a legacy Rails 3 app that got upgraded to 3.2, so the `jbuilder` gem was not in my Gemfile.

Once I added it, it works like a charm.

Comment: me. too, thanks for the suggestion,  I forget to check the GEMFILE until you tell me, lol